# find the appropriate learning rate using GridSearchCv in CNN and the error "ValueError"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gridsearchcv

I have a CNN and I want to find the appropriate learning rate using GridSearchCV. for this aim I used the following code:

```
batch_size = 32
epochs = 100
offset = 0 # for sometime with power outage
steps = 10000 #int(np.ceil(60000 / batch_size))
exp_id = 1
learning_rate = 1
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
batch_size = 128
epochs = 10

def create_model(lr=learning_rate):
    # define model
    
     return model

model_CV = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=epochs, 
                           batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
# define the grid search parameters
lr = [0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001]

param_grid = dict(lr=lr)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model_CV, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand])
```

but it produces this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=3 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=2.
```

could you please tell me what is this problem? how can I find the appropriate learning rates? my solution is true or not? my model has two inputs.
the complete error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\New folder\test_learningrate.py", line 245, in <module>
    grid_result = grid.fit([x_train,w_expand], [x_train,w_expand])

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 736, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 1188, in _run_search
    evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py", line 715, in evaluate_candidates
    cv.split(X, y, groups)))

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 334, in split
    .format(self.n_splits, n_samples))

ValueError: Cannot have number of splits n_splits=3 greater than the number of samples: n_samples=2.
```

Comment: Please show the complete error stack

Comment: I put the complete error.